# OneTimeSetUp: Invalid signature for SetUp or TearDown method: System-IDisposable-Dispose

Tags: f#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I would like to use nunit's teardownattribute combined with an implementation of System.IDisposable because I would like to make use of the `use` keyword in F#. Why do I receive this error when running the test?

```
[<TestFixture>] 
type public when_it_connects_to_database() =
    interface IDisposable with
        [<TearDown>]
        member this.Dispose() =
            this.connection.Dispose()

    member val public connection : ApplicationDbContext = createdatabasegateway true
        with get, set

    [<TestCase(true)>]
    member public this.it_succeeds(testmode:bool) : ApplicationDbContext =
        this.connection <- createdatabasegateway testmode
        this.connection

    [<Test>]
    member public this.it_can_read_the_database() =
        this.connection.AvailableExchanges.AsEnumerable().Count()
```

> Test Name:    it_can_read_the_database Test
>   FullName: tests.when_it_connects_to_database.it_can_read_the_database
>   Test
>   : line 29 Test Outcome:   Failed Test Duration:   0:00:00.0000001
>
> Result Message:   OneTimeSetUp: Invalid signature for SetUp or TearDown
>   method: System-IDisposable-Dispose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a Test Fixture implements IDisposable, NUnit disposes it after all the tests are run and any method marked with the `OneTimeTearDownAttribute` has run.

Marking your dispose method with `TearDownAttribute` would mean that you were attempting to dispose the object after **each** test and would clearly not be healthy for any tests after the first.

The actual error message you are seeing appears to be hiding the fact that you should not be using `TearDownAttribute` at all for this method. Simply implement IDisposable and the object will be disposed at the proper time.